# In Java, can I store a class type in variable, where the class is some subclass of an abstract class?

Tags: java, oop

This question arose because of this [cf4j example code](https://github.com/ferortega/cf4j/blob/master/src/main/java/es/upm/etsisi/cf4j/examples/recommender/MatrixFactorizationComparison.java). In particular, note that it creates a new QualityMeasure object for each recommender instance that is evaluated, and that **if we wanted to switch our evaluation method / QualityMeasure subclass used (currently `RMSE`), we would have to search-and-replace each QualityMeasure constructor**.

```
    // Evaluate PMF Recommender
    plot.addSeries("PMF");
    for (int factors : NUM_FACTORS) {
      Recommender pmf = new PMF(datamodel, factors, NUM_ITERS, RANDOM_SEED);
      pmf.fit();

      QualityMeasure rmse = new RMSE(pmf);  // NEED TO EDIT THIS...
      double rmseScore = rmse.getScore();
      plot.setValue("PMF", factors, rmseScore);
    }

    // Evaluate BNMF Recommender
    plot.addSeries("BNMF");
    for (int factors : NUM_FACTORS) {
      Recommender bnmf = new BNMF(datamodel, factors, NUM_ITERS, 0.2, 10, RANDOM_SEED);
      bnmf.fit();

      QualityMeasure rmse = new RMSE(bnmf);  // AND THIS...
      double rmseScore = rmse.getScore();
      plot.setValue("BNMF", factors, rmseScore);
    }

    // Evaluate BiasedMF Recommender
    plot.addSeries("BiasedMF");
    for (int factors : NUM_FACTORS) {
      Recommender biasedmf = new BiasedMF(datamodel, factors, NUM_ITERS, RANDOM_SEED);
      biasedmf.fit();

      QualityMeasure rmse = new RMSE(biasedmf);  // AND ALSO THIS...
      double rmseScore = rmse.getScore();
      plot.setValue("BiasedMF", factors, rmseScore);
    }
```

Is it instead possible to define a (fixed) variable that specifies what kind of subclass I will be using throughout?

```
   private static final QualityMeasureSubclass QM = RMSE;  // Can easily switch to MAE, MSE, etc.

   QualityMeasure qm = new QM(pmf);  // The constructor called depends on the subclass chosen above.
   double qmScore = qm.getScore();
   plot.setValue("PMF", factors, qmScore);
```

I do see that I can just factor out the common code, so I can adjust it in just that one place, but I don't know if the above is possible.

```
    private static double getQualityMeasureValue(Recommender rec) {
        QualityMeasure qm = new RMSE(rec);  // Only place we need to edit if we want to switch.
        return qm.getScore();
    }

    // Evaluate PMF Recommender
    plot.addSeries("PMF");
    for (int factors : NUM_FACTORS) {
      Recommender pmf = new PMF(datamodel, factors, NUM_ITERS, RANDOM_SEED);
      pmf.fit();
      plot.setValue("PMF", factors, getQualityMeasureValue(pmf));
    }
```

Edit: Cleaned up the last code section (no need for plot to be passed in).

Comment: You can do it just as you want - ie defining the subclass once, but you would need some utility methods that use reflection to to get the job done, and I’m not sure you are ready or willing to go down that path. Do some searching for how to use reflection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect job for a [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Assuming Java 8, your constructors can all be mapped to a `Function<Recommender, QualityMeasure>`.

```java
Map<Class<?>, Function<Recommender, QualityMeasure>> factories = Map.ofEntries(
        Map.entry(RMSE.class, RMSE::new),
        Map.entry(Other.class, Other::new));
```

You can then define a trivial function to call instead of your direct constructor expressions:

```java
QualityMeasure newQM(Class<?> QM, Recommender rec) {
    return factories.get(QM).apply(rec);
}
```

Feel free to change the key from `Class<?>` to a `String` or change the value to an actual lambda with additional (transformation) logic.

To avoid an NPE when trying to new up an unknown type, you can return a [Null Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern):

```java
factories.getOrDefault(cls, s -> null).apply(rec);
```

but note that in this case `apply` will then return `null` which is likely to cause problems further down the line. Depending on your overall structure it might be better to fail early in such a case:

```java
var ctor = Objects.requireNonNull(
        factories.get(cls),
        () -> "No ctor registered for class " + cls);
ctor.apply(rec);
```

Comment: I think this could be part of a solution, but it falls short of solving the last parts, eg `QualityMeasure qm = new QM(pmf);`, unless you define factories for all usages, which doesn’t seem to meet OP’s desire for an easy change.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks, I've extended my answer. Hopefully it is a bit clearer now.

Comment: @Bohemian: my answer assumes that all possibly `QualityMeasure` implementations are known beforehand, yes. If that's not the case, one would have to resort to forms of Java reflection, which can become a lot more complicated easily. I've answer with one suggestion for a possible solution. Anybody else can suggest different or better solutions.

Comment: @knittl It’s not a matter of being known. It’s the matter of needing a function for every use of every subclass, and there are several uses - your factory map deals with only one use.

Comment: @Kayaman I'm not following. My code can be used as `newQM(QM, pmf)` if I translate OP's suggested/expected code (`new QM(pmf)`). I don't see how this requires any more changes after the initial one-time change to make the code extensible.

Comment: @Bohemian sorry, I don't get your point. cf4j defines [8 predictors](https://github.com/ferortega/cf4j/tree/master/src/main/java/es/upm/etsisi/cf4j/qualityMeasure/prediction) which can easily be put into the map at application start. What do you mean with "a function for every use of every subclass"? There is only a single function (`newQM`) which acts as the factory. And you pass it the class you want and the constructor argument. Anyway, I've posted one potential solution. If there are better or more flexible alternatives, others can and should post them.

Comment: Oh, I missed that refactoring. But the QM class doesn't seem to depend on the Recommender class. It seems they just want an easy way to hardcode which QM is being used for everything. This doesn't actually seem to have much of a problem to solve if OP performs the refactoring to `getQualityMeasureValue(Recommender rec)`.

Comment: OK. If the only use case is calling the constructor, I guess it’s OK, although I would put such impl inside a factory object that has the newQM method.

Comment: Sure, `newQM` can be moved into a separate class to have a standalone factory _object_. I agree that this is clearer from an OOP viewpoint (the pattern is linked in the first sentence of the answer). The question was about calling the constructors of different (sub)classes, which all seem to have the same signature, so I wrote my answer to that use case.